# Start WhatsApp from URL HREF with custom text/content

Tags: android, html, android-intent, whatsapp

As you know using the whatsapp url scheme on iphone i can create the following link:

```
href="whatsapp://send?text=blahblah"
```

this is possible due to the url scheme support on ios.

im try to create the similar effect for android devices. (but no threw android app, just a normal html page).

to my understanding it should be something like:

```
href="intent://send/#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;s.text=test;end;"
```

or:

```
href="intent://send/#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;text=test;
     action=android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND; end"
```

or:

```
href="intent://send/#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;text=test;
      category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;end"
```

as you can see im really groping in the dark.
all the answers i've found on stackoverflow are talking about how to generate the intent threw the android app.

BUT thats not my case, i want to generate an href on a PHP/ASP server for an html page.

someone?
thanks!

Comment: you want to make a url that points to whatsapp? is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes! i want to create an url inside a browser link tag which point to whatsapp with a certain text message (no specific contact selected)

Comment: The link you need is to be used inside the device(not inside any app) but say from the browser of that device? right?

Comment: exactly right.
it seems it keeps opening the google play store and not the app itself.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking this will only open the google play store on whatsapp.
I want it to actually open the app and enter a message. Thanks for keep trying :)

Comment: Why will this only work in a emulator?

Comment: anyone else? i dont neeed it to open google store but the app itself

Comment: Manuel, We have winning answer!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

whatsapp now officially support url scheme over Android(Yey)!

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

for more details visit http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012

Comment: how do u send a message to a particular number? tried using pid but no luck on this one.

Answer (score 12):

Was working on the same Problem and found the solution:

```
href="intent://send/[countrycode_without_plus][number]#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

With a telephonenumber(+49 123 456 78)

```
href="intent://send/4912345678#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

Comment: Great, Thanks for this.
But you missed my intention, i meant sending a prewritten msg to a unknown contact.

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for the link with a known number.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer you where looking for is this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=my message&phone=+XXXXXXXXXXX&abid=+XXXXXXXXXXX">Whatsapp me please</a>
```

This code works both in Android and iOS thanks to the parameters "phone" and "abid" respectively.

**Update:**
If the user uses the web app, that link will do nothing. What I do is to provide that link for mobile and this other one for desktop users:

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=my message&phone=+XXXXXXXXXXX&abid=+XXXXXXXXXXX">Whatsapp me please</a>
```

You can do it through a CSS @mediaquery or just making the domain dynamic.

The reason why I use two different methods instead of the API "wa.me/?text=menssage", is to avoid the user a hard time trying to open whatsapp aswering questions he probably don't cares about.

Sorry for the late response, hope it helps somebody anyway.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryYudin
Yes it does it works like a charm. But I want to make a little update to my response. It works in both SO but only to open the app. So the users should have it installed. See the answer update.

Answer (score 3):

Whatsapp url scheme working only saved ids or numbers for jump message send screen. Android working with message activity for new phone numbers.

This script Looking phone os and create link for phone os.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

              if (matchMedia) {
                  var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)");
                  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
                  WidthChange(mq);
              }

              function WidthChange(mq) {
                  var isMobile = {
                      Android: function () {
                          return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
                      },
                      BlackBerry: function () {
                          return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
                      },
                      iOS: function () {
                          return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
                      },
                      Opera: function () {
                          return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
                      },
                      Windows: function () {
                          return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
                      },
                      any: function () {
                          return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
                      }
                  };




                  if (mq.matches) {
                      if (isMobile.Android()) {
                          $("a").attr("href", "intent://send/+905055555#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end");
                      } else {
                          $("a").attr("href", "tel:+905555555555");

                      }
                  };

              }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
href="intent://send/4912345678#Intent;
scheme=smsto;
package=com.whatsapp;
action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

This will not work with iPhones.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just easily create your own link and it will automatically handle it.

Immediately, you can create a chat with the number without adding them in your contact book.

Here is if you just want to create a chat. `15551234567` is your phone number with your country code as prefix, don't include the + sign.

https://wa.me/15551234567

Here is if you want to include a pre-filled text message.

[https://wa.me/15551234567?text=Hello There. General Kenobi!](https://wa.me/15551234567?text=Hello%20There.%20General%20Kenobi!)

For more information, check out WhatsApp own documentation.

https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/26000030/

Answer (score -2):

I used this `href="intent://send/4912345678#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end`

but in this code cant include the text