# HREF for sending message using whatsapp

Tags: android, html, android-intent, href

I'm trying to set an href from an `<a>` tag that should on click open WhatsApp and create a new conversation with a specified number.

I checked this post: [Start WhatsApp from URL HREF with custom text/content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500570/start-whatsapp-from-url-href-with-custom-text-content)

Meanwhile, when I click the intent, it tries to open whatsapp but an alert pops saying:

"Looks like you want to send a WhatsApp message to a telephone number not on WhatsApp. Your contacts must have an WhatsApp installation to be able to cumnicate. Touch SMS to send a common SMS to your contact or touch Invite to send an invitation for whatsapp using SMS."

**The strange thing is that the specified number actually has Whatsapp installed!**

Comment: Yes... That's true. Coz only when both the sides have WhatsApp installed, WhatsApp could send a message.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, and they do!

Comment: Eeeks... LoL. Then :(