# Whatsapp html call link

Tags: android, html, call, whatsapp

Is there a way to add a link on my website that will say "Call now" and when it's pressed the *user can call from their whats app.*

Any help would be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: It seems there is the same question already answered for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962588/1162790

Comment: This was worked for me, `whatsapp://send?text=MESSAGE&phone=+NUMERO&abid=+NUMERO`
Obviusly "+NUMERO" is the wsp number and "MESSAGE" the preloaded message` put in in `href` attribute

Answer (score 6):

Creating a telephone link is much like creating a mailto: link... 
your link would look like this:

```
<a href="tel:1234561234">Call ME!</a>
```

this tells browser plugins and smart phones that the link being followed is a telephone number and to use the default telephone application installed.

EDIT:

Based on feedback and what other users have commented, I would suggest trying this, I am unsure if this will work as expected but maybe try some different combinations.

```
<a href="whatsapp://tel:3216541234"></a>
```

Or

```
<a href="whatsapp://3216541234"></a>
```

if this works for you please mark the other user who posted this information as the right answer... I simply referenced his/her content, I knew this kind of thing existed but did not know the url design so they do deserve the credit.

SECOND EDIT: 
Visit this website to see kind of how this should work: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012

based on what I see here, I would actually guess  it's more like:

```
<a href="whatsapp://call?number=##########"></a>
```

Please let us know the working result so I can modify my response to have the right answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for that, but this only opens my phones default dial pad. I need it to open with whatsapp..

Comment: Sorry they did not work. I did how ever see this in another post.                                                                  <a href="intent://send/0123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">                                                      this seems to send messages not make calls. As ya know I need it to make calls

Comment: Gahh so sorry then, I am afraid I will be of no more help... :/ Best of luck to you then! Maybe contact Whatsapp and ask them directly? Not time efficient (usually) but if anyone knows, they would. :)

Comment: Actually, instead of `number`, you should use `phone` to pass the WhatsApp contact phone. More details [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251). It also works for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

WhatsApp listens to URL patterns `whatsapp://*`, although I can't find any public documentation for it. Here is the documentation for sending a message for [Android](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012) and [iOS](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) respectively.

Comment: so what would the full link with a number in it look like.